# My PC wifi can't detect a particular hotspot device

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, network-adapter

Just few days ago, I was able to use the wireless hotspot network **ICTD5** in my work place. But now, my computer is not able to detect it. It can detect other networks including my phone's hotspot but not **ICTD5**. I've been able to use the internet on **ICTD5** using my phone and my tablet, but my PC just can't see **ICTD5**. Other people's PCs can.

I've installed the latest driver for my wifi adapter as well as tried different things I saw online like uninstalling and reintsalling the adapter, disabling and reenabling it, restarting my PC etc, but none have worked.

I'd appreciate any help in finding what is going wrong. I use a **HP G60 G3** with **Ralink RT3290 wifi adapter**.

Comment: have you asked windows to forget the network? http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-delete-or-forget-wireless-network-profiles-windows-10

Comment: @FrankThomas can't even see the network to tell windows to forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Internet, Ralink RT3290 is an old WiFi adapter supporting 802.11 b/g/n only (2.4 GHz band, WiFi 4 or earilier). It is possible that your workplace hotspot switched to 802.11 n/ac/ax only (5 GHz band, WiFi 5/6) so your adapter can't find it.

To confirm this, use your phone or any device that can connect to this network and check `Protocol`, `Network Band` (should be 2.4 GHz for your adapter to find it) and `Network channel` (should be 1~13 for 2.4 GHz band).

*Note*: APs nowadays may broadcast 2.4 GHz band and 5 GHz band simultaneously so this method is not that accurate.

You can also contact your network administrator to confirm the problem.

If this is the case, you'll have to update your network adapter (buy one that supports WiFi 5/6).